# How can I use a User Control as a Diagram Node in XamDiagram?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, infragistics

Working with `XamDiagram` in the Infragistics WPF controls library, I'm looking for a way to use existing user-controls as Diagram Nodes instead of the out-of-the-box rectangles/circles/basic shapes.

If I inherit from `DiagramNode`, I can set the `DisplayTemplate` and `EditTemplate` properties, but would need to provide a type of `System.Windows.DataTemplate`. Since the user controls I want to use are fairly complex and pre-existing, I'd like to avoid creating a brand-new DataTemplate for it.

How can I use a user control as a `DiagramNode`?

Answer (score 1):

Both the DiagramNode and DiagramConnection have DisplayTemplate and EditTemplates you can use. It is actually all very well documented [here](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/2014.2/CLR4.0/?page=xamDiagram_Styling_Items_Templates.html) and for more questions you can check [this](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WPF/2014.2/CLR4.0/?page=xamDiagram.html) out.